# How to put a frame over a page?

Tags: texworks, frame

I'd like to have a frame along the margins of a page. I'm working on TeXWorks. I don't know how can I do it, can anyone help me please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  A simple solution to get started  is `\usepackage{showframe}`.  If that does not solve your issue, please edit the question and include mode details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for lorem ipsum
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\backgroundsetup{
    placement=center,
    scale=1,
    angle=0,
    opacity=.4,
    nodeanchor=center,
    contents={
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \draw[magenta, line width=1cm] 
            ($(current page.north east)$) -- ($(current page.south east)$);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum[5-9]
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

**EDIT1:**
If you want the four margins marked change the last line before `\end{tikzpicture}` with this one:

```
($(current page.north west)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)$);
```

and you have the desired result:

[image]

**EDIT2:**
Lastly if you want to color only the tree external margins you have to change the same lini with this one:

```
($(current page.north west)$) -- ($(current page.north east)$)--($(current page.south east)$)--($(current page.south west)$);
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: The OP used the word "margins". Perhaps you could expand your answer adding the others three sides.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to add something like flowers, shapes along margins?

Comment: @JohnMax6 For this adds you have to ask a new question.

Comment: +1 Nice effort and clean code.

Comment: @SimonDispa Work done for 1  margin. 4 margins and 3 margins.